Instagram API Messages Going to General Instead of Primary — How to Fix?
I’m trying to send automated responses via Instagram Messenger using the Meta API. Here’s a snippet of my code:
async function handleInstagramMessage(messagingItem) {
  try {
    if (messagingItem.message && messagingItem.message.text) {
      // Ignore echo messages
      // if (messagingItem.message.is_echo) {
      //   console.log("Skipping echo message.");
      //   return;
      // }

      const messageId = messagingItem.message.mid;
      const message = messagingItem.message.text.trim();
      const senderId = messagingItem.sender.id;
      const recipientId = messagingItem.recipient.id;
      const timestamp = messagingItem.timestamp;
     
      const pageTokens = getPageTokens();
      const currentPage = pageTokens.find(page => page.instagram_page_id === senderId);
      


            // Check if sender ID exists in ownPageSenderIds
      if (ownPageSenderIds[senderId]) {
        const senderDetails = ownPageSenderIds[senderId];

        // Respond to "send" by sending an image
        if (message === "scanner") {
          console.log('Message is "SEND" - Sending image');
          await sendInstagramImage(recipientId, senderDetails.imageUrl, currentPage.access_token);
          console.log('Sent image to recipient:', recipientId);
          return;
        }

        // Respond to "email" by sending email details
        if (message === "email") {
          console.log('Message is "EMAIL" - Sending email details');
          const responseText = `${senderDetails.email}`;
          await sendInstagramMessage(recipientId, responseText, currentPage.access_token);
          console.log('Sent email details to recipient:', recipientId);
          return;
        }
      } else {
        console.log(`Sender ID: ${senderId} not found in ownPageSenderIds.`);
      }




      // const pageTokens = getPageTokens();
      const currentPageRESPONSE = pageTokens.find(page => page.instagram_page_id === recipientId);

      if (!currentPageRESPONSE) {
        console.error(`No access token found for Instagram page ID: ${senderId}`);
        return;
      }

      if (processedMessageIds.has(messageId)) {
        console.log(`Skipping already processed message ID: ${messageId}`);
        return;
      }

      processedMessageIds.add(messageId);


      // Get time-based greeting
      const timeGreeting = getTimeBasedGreetingFromTimestamp(timestamp);
      
      // Fetch username
      const username = await getUsername(senderId, currentPageRESPONSE.access_token);

      // Handle the question with both username and timeGreeting
      const responseText = handleQuestion(message, username, timeGreeting);
      
      if (responseText !== "I'm sorry, I didn't understand that. Could you please rephrase?") {
        await sendInstagramMessage(senderId, responseText, currentPageRESPONSE.access_token);
      } else {
        console.log("Message did not match any question triggers.");
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error in handleInstagramMessage:", error);
  }
}

async function sendInstagramMessage(recipientId, message, pageAccessToken) {
  try {
    console.log(`Sending message "${message}" to ${recipientId}`);
    const response = await axios.post(`https://graph.facebook.com/v20.0/me/messages`, {
      recipient: { id: recipientId },
      message: { text: message },
      messaging_type: "RESPONSE"
    }, {
      headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${pageAccessToken}` }
    });
    console.log('Message sent successfully:', response.data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error sending message:', error.response ? error.response.data : error.message);
  }
}


The problem: All messages are going to the General inbox instead of Primary. I’ve checked for:
Proper access tokens.
Valid user permissions.
Whether the user has interacted with the bot before.
Still, the issue persists. Is there a way to control the placement of messages (General vs. Primary)?
Environment:
Node.js
Instagram Graph API
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
